# List all the git branches

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I have written a toy script to list all the git branches in `cwd`. I am interested in knowing how can I make this code more modular and flexible.
For example I would like to have features like:

1. List only local branches.
2. List only remote branches.
3. Etc.

---

```
const os = require('os');
const cp = require('child_process');

const REGEX_STAR = /^\*\s*/g;

const promiseExec = (cmd) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cp.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(lines(`${stdout}`));
    });
  });

const lines = (str) =>
  str.trim().split(os.EOL).map((line) =>
    line.trim().replace(REGEX_STAR, '')
  );

const branches = () =>
  promiseExec('git branch -a')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });

branches();
```

Comment: for start I would to use git one of those git libraries for node, [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit) looks fine.

Comment: next, I would to create a Class for your purposes, instead of own promiseExec I would to use promisify libraries, in short - better to use common libraries than to write own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the data and leave it to the consumer what to do with it. That way, `branches` becomes a generic data grabber. If you want to have printer functions, keep them separate from the raw command.

Your Promise wrapper appears to expect the output of the `branches` command. Move the use of `lines` to the `branches` function instead.

Also, arrow functions with single arguments can omit the parens.

```
const promiseExec = (cmd) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  cp.exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    else resolve(stdout);
  });
});

const branchLines = (str) => str.trim().split(os.EOL).map(line => line.trim().replace(REGEX_STAR, ''));

const branches = () => promiseExec('git branch -a').then(res => branchLines(res));

const printBranches = () => branches().then(res => console.log(res));

// Print manually
branches().then(res => console.log(res));

// or have a printer function do it
printbranches();
```

Comment: What about extending features?